# Testing HTML5 game in browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hey everyone Im new to web development and am writing a simple HTML5 game with three files(index.html, style.css, and game.js) in a folder and I wasnt sure if there was a way to test it in the browser?

Ive tried opening up the html file in the browser but it doesnt have any functionality or visual differences from the .js file. Im wondering if I can do a localhost or something like that so I can see the progress.

Comment: Did you link the  js file to the html file ? Unless the game runs on a server, you shouldnt need to launch it on a host. As long as they are in the same folder and they are LINKED. it should work

Comment: Make sure the javascript is loaded. Check the console for errors. Use a tool like Chrome Developer tools (Press f-12) or firebufg for firefox to make sure all your resources are loaded: use the network feature of the tools to check. Also make sure to flush your cache after making changes as static files such as html, javasript and css are cached by the browser.

Comment: @Jon P the flushing of the cache worked its functional now, wow thank you I had no clue that could even be an issue for something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that all the files are in the same folder and you link them as such:

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="game.js"></script>
```

Then you can just open the [html](/questions/tagged/html) file in your browser, as long as you don't require a server to run your app, the code will run fine.

Comment: Yeah I actually had everything in the correct spot and the exact code you posted above which lead to me asking the question, strange?

Comment: @JLuse so what exactly do you get when you open it? Are you opening the file correctly? What platform and browser are you using to open it?

Comment: When I open the index file I have a canvas which shows up in the browser but Im adding some js to give it animation and nothing shows. Im opening it by dragging it from sublime to the browser which is Chrome.

Comment: Check the console to see if there is an `ERR: FILE NOT FOUND`. If not, it means there is something wrong with your code, and not your file loading.

Comment: thanks for your time I followed direction on flushing the cache which actually worked had no clue about it.

Comment: @JLuse, no problem, if this answer helped you would you mind accepting it by clicking on the green check next to my answer? It gives you reputation too :)

Answer (score 0):

verify you  and  tags, if you have any src using // instead http:// (or https://) the script will not load

this will not work locally

```
<head>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="hello">Hello world!</h1>
    <script>
        $('#hello').text('Hello!');
    </script>
</body>
```

this will

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="hello">Hello world!</h1>
    <script>
        $('#hello').text('Hello!');
    </script>
</body>
```

hope is something like that